# Cannot launch homepage with webpack + gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

I am learning Webpack for the first time and trying to create a project with it. I want to run the `gulp` command, so that it launches the webpack-dev-server on my browser automatically, opening `index.html`. I also want to use hot reload of webpack to load modified assets without refreshing the browser. My code is given below:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:9080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]  
};

module.exports = config;
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config.js');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task("webpack-dev-server", function(callback) {
    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
            '*': 'http://localhost:5000'
        },
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    }).listen(6000, "localhost", function(err) {
        if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['webpack-dev-server']);
```

bundle.js is created successfully by webpack, but the browser does not open to `localhost:9080`. When I open it manually, it says `Unable to connect`. Also, changing a JS file does not automatically cause bundle.js to be rebuilt. I have followed many tutorials, but cannot get it right. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using Webpack with Gulp in your fairly simple scenario. Just use Webpack. Using it with Gulp will overcomplicate your workflow and learning experience even more so if you're just getting into it.

Try to break it down a bit instead:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    './src'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Then run the Dev Server like:

> webpack-dev-server --hot --inline

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and specifying the port does open the page at localhost:9000, but the browser does not show the updated file when something in a JSX file is changed. Also,  I understand that this can be done with webpack only, but in my project I am planning to perform other tasks as well, for which I may need Gulp. Hence I want to use Gulp...